# How to deploy this web application?

Tags: python, reactjs, nginx, deployment, fastapi

I have created a web platform and apparently, I do have big issues with its deployment now. I am still learning and would be great to get some guidance from someone more experienced.

Structure of the app is as follows:

- FRONTEND -> coded in react.js, using npm start to run development server.
- API -> coded in Python. Uses FastAPI as an API and sqlalchemy for sql translation.

---

Essentially, an API is an internal service that collects and scrapes data from various sources. It also starts to run a scraper, coded using python, after sending a request to the specific endpoint. This scraper on the other hand uses splash, which is run on Docker, to render Javascript from targeted websites. Afterwards, frontend (react.js app) can use the data.

---

I was able to create a Docker setup using docker-compose method. Everything works on the localhost, because I can refer to specific ports and easily send http requests to my splash server on localhost. Problem starts to occur when I go live, because I do not know how to configure my nginx, so it can be all run efficiently between frontend-backend.
Current folder setup is like below:

- .env
- docker-compose.yml
- api

  - dockerfile
  - .env
  - all relevant API files, including python codes
- frontend

  - dockerfile
  - .env
  - all relevant react.js files
- nginx

  - default.conf
  - dockerfile

Docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    container_name: postgresql_db
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=${PGADMIN_EMAIL}
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=${PGADMIN_PASSWORD}
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: unless-stopped

  splash:
    container_name: splash
    image: scrapinghub/splash
    command: --maxrss 2048 --max-timeout 300 --disable-lua-sandbox --verbosity 1
    platform: linux/amd64
    volumes:
      - ./data/filters:/etc/splash/filters
      - ./data/js-profiles:/etc/splash/js-profiles
      - ./data/lua_modules:/etc/splash/lua_modules
      - ./data/proxy-profiles:/etc/splash/proxy-profiles
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - api
      - frontend
    links:
      - api

  api:
    container_name: api
    build:
      dockerfile: dockerfile
      context: ./api
    command: bash -c "alembic upgrade head && uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --reload"
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always

  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      dockerfile: dockerfile
      context: ./frontend
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./frontend:/app
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build:
      dockerfile: dockerfile
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-available/default
    depends_on:
      - api
      - frontend
    restart: always
```

Nginx - default.conf:

```
upstream frontend {
  server frontend:3000;
}

upstream api {
  server api:8000;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server; 
  listen [::]:80 default_server; 

  server_name domain.com www.domain.com

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://frontend;
  }
  
  location /api/ {
      proxy_pass http://api;
  }
  
}
```

Is it correct way to deploy it to the live server? Should I also include my dbadmin and postgresql_db into docker? I am currently using digital ocean as my cloud provider. Can someone guide me pls, because I do not know how to go live?

Thanks in advance, any help is invaluable!

Comment: Here you can find some hints: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/

Comment: I probably did not make myself clear. I know how to containerize the entire application and put it up to the localhost. I am just not sure how to deploy it onto my domain, where I cannot use any ports beyond :80. This is perhaps where nginx comes into play and I am unable to set it up properly.

Comment: You can use [vercel.com](https://vercel.com) to deploy your app for free or Heroku.